# I cannot save vertex editing in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, editing, vertices

I am trying to adjust the vertex of polygons so ensure it matches the reference polygon layer. Snapping tool is ON, and tolerance is 6. However, after dragging the vertex of one polygon to the corner point of the reference layer, clicking "saving edits", the vertex dragged would go back to its previous position.  My editing is not saved at all! I checked projection which is Fine, and I created a new polygon within the layer, and adjusted the vertex, clicked "saving edits", and the vertex went back to the previous position. Could anyone give suggestions on a possible solution?

Comment: Can you please add some information about the data format and the data source.  That will give more clues about what's going on.  Certain formats don't allow edits.  I've had problems editing geojson data in QGIS.

Comment: Did you right-click to finish editing before saving your changes?

Comment: Can you also try without snapping turned on to begin with, just to see if that makes a difference.